# Problem with Action msg

Tags: ros, action, ros-kinetic, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I wrote my own Action msg for ROS. This is the msg :

```
#goal
string start_phrase
---
#result 
point coordinates
---
#feedback
duration time_elapsed
```

This is my changes in Cmake :

```
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED
 COMPONENTS   actionlib_msgs  
 geometry_msgs   rospy   std_msgs  
 message_generation ) add_action_files(
 DIRECTORY action    FILES
 camera.action
 
 )

 ## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed
 here  generate_messages(   
 DEPENDENCIES    geometry_msgs   
 actionlib_msgs    std_msgs   )

 catkin_package(
 #  INCLUDE_DIRS include
 #  LIBRARIES camera_action   CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs rospy
 actionlib_msgs
 #  DEPENDS system_lib )
```

This is my Package :

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

When I try to catkin_make my src i get this error :

> Could not find messages which
> '/home/michael/catkin_ws/devel/share/camera_action/msg/cameraAction.msg'
> depends on.  Did you forget to specify
> generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?
>
> Cannot locate message [point] in
> package [camera_action] with paths
> [['/home/michael/catkin_ws/devel/share/camera_action/msg']]
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:307
> (include)
> camera_action/CMakeLists.txt:73
> (generate_messages)

I see that there is a problem with point. Does someone have any idea ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343819/problem-with-action-msg/) by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, `point` is no [built-in data type](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields) (and not a relative one, apparently).

Thus need to specify it in the message description as `package/Message`. You are most probably referring to `geometry_msgs/Point`.

In fact, even though you can have relative names (see citation below), I'd recommend to always use the full package/Message format...

> When embedding other Message descriptions, the type name may be relative (e.g. "Point32") if it is in the same package; otherwise it must be the full Message type (e.g. "std_msgs/String")

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2020-02-11**:
If I specify it like geometry_msgs/Point how should I write this in the Cmake file. geometry_msgs or geometry_msgs/Point and where ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-02-12**:
In the `CMakeLists.txt` and the `package.xml`, you only depend on the package. I.e. on `geometry_msgs`. In the code where you use it, you need to specify the exact type (i.e. `geometry_msgs/Point`).

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2020-02-12**:
Thank you, that worked!